# Sacar la mejor venta por mes por cliente - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola amigos de la comunidad, me quedé varado en una consulta en donde se tiene que sacar la información de los clientes indicando el producto que más han comprado en cada mes, indicando su cantidad respectiva.

[image: En el caso del cliente ALFKI, salen sus productos más comprados particionados por el mes y luego por el año.]

Quisiera sacar de esa consulta, el mejor producto vendido por cada mes, es decir, que los meses no se repitan. En el caso del cliente ALFKI, deberían quedar sólo 5 registros y así los que queden para los demás códigos de clientes.

Aquí está la consulta paso por paso(El 4to paso pertenece a la consulta de la imagen, es ahí donde me quedé jaja):

--  1er Paso

```
select C.CustomerID as CódigoCliente, P.ProductID as CódigoProducto, 
YEAR(O.OrderDate) as Año, MONTH(O.OrderDate) as Mes, SUM(D.Quantity) as 
Cantidad
from [Order Details] D inner join Orders O on D.OrderID = O.OrderID 
                       inner join Products P on D.ProductID = P.ProductID 
                       inner join Customers C on O.CustomerID = 
C.CustomerID
group by C.CustomerID, P.ProductID, YEAR(O.OrderDate), MONTH(O.OrderDate)
```

--  2do Paso

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By X.CódigoCliente Order By X.Año asc, 
       X.Mes asc, X.Cantidad desc)  as Posición, X.CódigoCliente, 
       X.CódigoProducto, X.Cantidad, X.Mes, X.Año from
       (select C.CustomerID as CódigoCliente, P.ProductID as 
       CódigoProducto, YEAR(O.OrderDate) as Año, MONTH(O.OrderDate) as Mes, 
       SUM(D.Quantity) as Cantidad
       from [Order Details] D inner join Orders O on D.OrderID = O.OrderID 
                       inner join Products P on D.ProductID = P.ProductID 
                       inner join Customers C on O.CustomerID = 
       C.CustomerID
       group by C.CustomerID, P.ProductID, YEAR(O.OrderDate), 
       MONTH(O.OrderDate)) as X
```

--  3er Paso

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Y.CódigoCliente, Y.Año Order By 
       Y.Año asc, Y.Mes, Y.Cantidad desc),  Y.CódigoCliente, 
       Y.CódigoProducto, Y.Cantidad, Y.Mes, Y.Año from
       (select ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By X.CódigoCliente Order By 
       X.Año asc, X.Mes asc, X.Cantidad desc)  as Posición, 
       X.CódigoCliente, X.CódigoProducto, X.Cantidad, X.Mes, X.Año from
       (select C.CustomerID as CódigoCliente, P.ProductID as 
       CódigoProducto, YEAR(O.OrderDate) as Año, MONTH(O.OrderDate) as Mes, 
       SUM(D.Quantity) as Cantidad
       from [Order Details] D inner join Orders O on D.OrderID = O.OrderID 
                       inner join Products P on D.ProductID = P.ProductID 
                       inner join Customers C on O.CustomerID = 
       C.CustomerID
       group by C.CustomerID, P.ProductID, YEAR(O.OrderDate), 
       MONTH(O.OrderDate)) as X) as Y
       group by Y.CódigoCliente, Y.CódigoProducto, Y.Mes, Y.Año, Y.Cantidad
```

PD: Trabajo con la base de datos **Northwind.**

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Trata de ser conciso en la pregunta... No se entiende que hacen las consultas que publicaste... te fallan todas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás confundiendo de más y repitiendo cálculos que no te sirven. Aquí hay un código que no he probado pero debería de dar el resultado.

```
WITH VentasPorMes AS(
    SELECT C.CustomerID    AS CodigoCliente,
        P.ProductID        AS CodigoProducto,
        YEAR(O.OrderDate)  AS Año,
        MONTH(O.OrderDate) AS Mes,
        SUM(D.Quantity)    AS Cantidad
    FROM [Order Details] D
    INNER JOIN Orders O ON D.OrderID = O.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products P ON D.ProductID = P.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Customers C ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    GROUP BY C.CustomerID,
        P.ProductID,
        YEAR(O.OrderDate),
        MONTH(O.OrderDate)
),
VentasPorMesOrdenadas AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY X.CódigoCliente, X.Año, X.Mes
                                ORDER BY X.Cantidad DESC ) AS Posicion,
        X.CodigoCliente,
        X.CodigoProducto,
        X.Cantidad,
        X.Mes,
        X.Año
    FROM VentasPorMes AS X
)
SELECT X.CodigoCliente,
        X.CodigoProducto,
        X.Cantidad,
        X.Mes,
        X.Año
FROM VentasPorMesOrdeneadas
WHERE Posicion = 1;
```